# To-do list refreshing upon hitting enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Upon submitting a to-do list item, the page refreshes. I'm using e.stopPropagation() in an attempt to prevent the default page reload (doesn't help).

Here's my JavaScript. For my full code, see my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/VXmPrO).

```
$(function() {

  $('.button').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let toAdd = $('input[name=listItem]').val();
    // Inserts li as first child of ul
    $('ul').prepend('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
    // Clears input box after clicking '+'
    $('input[name=listItem]').val('');
  });

  // Upon hitting enter, triggers button click and prevents page from refreshing and event bubbling and capturing/trickling
  $('input[name=listItem]').keypress(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('.button').click();
    };
  });

  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    // Upon list item click, toggleClass() adds class 'strike' for it and fadeOut() completely hides it
    $(this).toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.preventDefault()` on the button to prevent the form submission. You don't need `e.stopPropagation` in either handler.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to disable the default `keypress` behaviour, you need to use `preventDefault` within the `keypress` event handler.

Try changing to `e.stopPropagation` to `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$('input[name=listItem]').keypress(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('.button').click();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `<button class="button">+</button>`

To `<button type="button" class="button">+</button>` In your HTML

Since you haven't specified the type of button it is treated as a **submit** type button. And hence on its click the page is being submitted. So you just have to specify the button type as **button**.

or just change `e.stopPropagation();` to `e.preventDefault();`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add `e.preventDefault()` after the button `click` function

```
if (e.which === 13) {
      $('.button').click();
      e.preventDefault()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the form is submitting when you trigger `click` on the button. Try adding this in your code:

```
$('form[name=listForm]').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I would suggest to remove the form, since you are never submitting it.
Otherwise, I would suggest to just handle the form submission, and make you actions upon that event. 
This way:

```
$(function() {

  $('form[name=listForm]').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let toAdd = $('input[name=listItem]').val();
    // Inserts li as first child of ul
    $('ul').prepend('<li>' + toAdd + '</li>');
    // Clears input box after clicking '+'
    $('input[name=listItem]').val('');
  });

  // Upon hitting enter, triggers button click and prevents page from refreshing and event bubbling and capturing/trickling
  $('input[name=listItem]').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('form[name=listForm]').submit();
    };
  });

  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    // Upon list item click, toggleClass() adds class 'strike' for it and fadeOut() completely hides it
    $(this).toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');
  });

});
```